# Marching cubes - where does the isosurface cut the edge?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I am currently trying to figure out the insane marching cube algorithm (a.k.a. "3D contouring" or "Surface reconstruction"). According to Paul Bourke,

> The position that it [the isosurface] cuts the edge will be linearly interpolated, the ratio of the length between the two vertices will be the same as the ratio of the isosurface value to the values at the vertices of the grid cell.

I can't seem to wrap my head around this statement. Does he mean something like: $$\frac{L_1}{L_2}=\frac{I}{I_1+I_2}$$

Where $L_1$ is the distance between the cut and vertex 1, $L_2$ is the distance between the cut and vertex 2, $I$ is the isosurface level, $I_1$ is the isosurface value of vertex 1, and $I_2$ is the isosurface value of vertex 2.

Is this equation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not surprising that you can't seem to wrap your head around it; all the better for your head; it's terribly worded. No, that equation can't be correct, because you're forming the ratio of one value to the sum of two on the right-hand side, which yields $1/2$ for constant values whereas the left-hand side is not always $1/2$.

What he means is probably something like

$$
\frac{L_1}{L_2}=\frac{I-I_1}{I_2-I}\;,
$$

but a more convenient form of that relationship is

$$
I=\frac{I_1L_2+I_2L_1}{L_1+L_2}\;.
$$

Comment: Must be. Thanks.